# Update nodejs scraper json every X minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js

i've developed a scraper that retrieve some information for me, and i have this on heroku. it works fine except that i can't see the real-time updates (my app shows the first fetched values, not the actual one)

my code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const app = express();
const myarr= []

app.get('/mylink', (req, res) =>{
  axios.get(myUrl,{
    responseEncoding: 'binary'
  })
    .then((response) => {
      const html = response.data
      const $ = cheerio.load(html)

      $('tr', html).each(function (parentIdx) {

          const title = $(this).find('a.tw-hidden.lg\\:tw-flex.font-bold.tw-items-center.tw-justify-between').text()
      
          myarr.push({
            title
           
          })
      })
  

      res.json(myarr)
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server avviato ed in ascolto sulla PORTA ${PORT}`))
```

how can i get updated results?

Comment: did you try using cron jobs?

Comment: Real time how, when the site updates or on a schedule? Running in a cron job might be one option.

Comment: yes when the site update the value, i can get the updated one instantly...can anyone explain how to setup a cronjob? i'm on heroku, sorry is my first experience

Comment: Separation of concerns is the right path for you, I'd go with the cron option.

Comment: i dont' know how to setup a cron...can someone explain please? i will accept the answer asap

Comment: you can simply import the cron module and schedule it based on the frequency you need. this is the npm page for your reference:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron   if you have multiple servers then make sure only one server setup this cron scheduler.

Comment: i've tried but i get    Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: no one on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get immediate updated results when the site updates unless you own the website, in which case you can use websockets or a web hook. Failing that, your only other choice is to schedule a cronjob (as others have said) to check the website for changes at a specified interval (once per day, once per hour, etc.). For heroku, you can easily setup this up like so:

1. Your script's first line needs to be `#!/usr/bin/env node`. The rest of it can be your code.
2. Place your script in the `/bin` folder (create it if does not exist) at root level.
3. Install the free "Heroku Scheduler" add-on in Heroku.
4. Click on the "Heroku Scheduler" link to configure it, click on "Add Job", choose your interval, then set the run command to `myScript.js` so that the full command is `$ myScript.js`. Obviously, `myScript.js` referrers to whatever your script's file name is.
5. Wait for the specified interval and check your heroku logs for the `console.log` output.